# Save or view a form (using Django template system)

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates

I have a form, which must have two ways of submitting. If user pressing "add" button it is saving in the database and if user pressing "view" button the form saving in the session, so it's just a view. Both of the processes are synchronous, pages are reloads every time the submit button pressed.

How to submit the form in two different addresses or how to add request.POST variable to specify the logic in the backend? Is it possible by html, django template system or javascript?

```
<table>    
    <form class="add-cv" method="POST" action="{% url add_cv %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!--A lot of form fields-->
    <tr>
        <td>            
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Add" %}">
            <input type="submit" value="{% trans "View" %}">
        </td>        
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the name attribute to the submit `name="submit1"` and `name="submit2"` and then, you can difference between them in your add_*cv* view:

```
if "submit1" in request.POST:
    do something
elif "submit2" in request.POST:
    do something
```

Comment: Woah! It's really clean! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using both javascript or your django view function.

To send the request to your view function ad then do the appropriate action, modify your html form like this:

```
<table>    
<form class="add-cv" method="POST" action="{% url add_cv %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<!--A lot of form fields-->
<tr>
    <td>            
        <input type="submit" name="submit_Add" value="{% trans "Add" %}">
        <input type="submit" name="submit_View" value="{% trans "View" %}">
    </td>        
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

This will ensure that you can find either 'submit_Add' or 'submit_Value' in the keys of the request.POST dictionary send to the view, depending on whichever submit button was clicked. You can differentiate this in your views like this:

```
def YourView(request):
  if "submit_Add" in request.POST:
       # Actions to add the values in the database.
  elif "submit_View" in request.POST:
       # Actions to save the values in the session.
```

Or you can use javascript to differentiate the buttons.( But this would be a round about method and should only be used if you absolutely cannot reload your page. )
To use javascript modify your html code like this:

```
<table>    
<form class="add-cv" method="POST" action="{% url add_cv %}">
{% csrf_token %}
<!--A lot of form fields-->
<tr>
    <td>            
        <input type="button" onclick="func_Add();" value="{% trans "Add" %}">
        <input type="button" onclick="func_View();" value="{% trans "View" %}">
    </td>        
</tr>
</form>
</table>
```

The define the two functions in your template.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function func_Add(){
     //Required 'Add' actions.
   }

  function func_View(){
     //Required 'View' actions.
   }
</script>
```